# datatables jquery header not working in production, but works fine locally

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables, coffeescript

i have a datatable in a rails app, this is all i do for the coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#candidates-table').dataTable( {
    paging: false
    })
```

generated javacript is below:

```
{jQuery(function(){return $("#candidates-table").dataTable({paging:!1})})}
```

On localhost, it works fine, the headers are clickable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBLDU.png

On production, the headers do not have the arrows and are not clickable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtZ3s.png

There's nothing in the environment files that would make the difference, anyone seen this before?

Comment: If you click on the headers does it still sort properly? I think just the arrow icons are missing.

Comment: How are you loading the datatables plugin? Show the `<script>` line in your question, please.

Comment: answering both questions here.  the header does nothing when clicked.  and i posted the coffeescript, i'll edit to show the final generated javascript